Dynamically selecting queues in Airflow
Is it possible to dynamically assign a queue to a task in Airflow based on runtime conditions? For instance, I want to determine the queue for a task based on an XCom value provided by a previous task?
I am designing a system consisting of multiple Celery workers, and I want to send specific tasks to specific workers. If this is possible, how can this be achieved? Otherwise, how else could I approach this problem?

You can use manual routing option in celery

Define multiple queues in your Celery configuration

from kombu import Queue

app.conf.task_queues = (
    Queue('default', routing_key='default.#'),
    Queue('high_priority', routing_key='high_priority.#'),
    Queue('low_priority', routing_key='low_priority.#'),
)


Call Task with Specified Queue:

# Send to high_priority queue
my_task.apply_async(args=['urgent_task'], queue='high_priority')

# Send to low_priority queue
my_task.apply_async(args=['non_urgent_task'], queue='low_priority')


You can start a worker that listens to a specific queue by using the -Q (or --queues) option when starting the worker.

celery -A my_app worker -Q high_priority -n worker_high_priority@%h

Checkout manual routing documentation

Thank you for your response! I'm actually looking for an implementation in Airflow (which uses Celery in the backend).
